# Exclude Macro from working on certain sheets

Tags: excel, vba

How do I exclude these sheets from a macro that will run through the workbook?
Having trouble finishing the code because I'm not familiar with excluding sheets.

What I have so far:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
   If sh.Name <> "Apples" And sh.Name <> "Oranges" And ws.Name <> "Grapes" Then
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a variable that represents the names of all sheets to exclude:

```
Const excludeSheets as String = "Apples,Oranges,Grapes,David,Hector,Sheet1"
```

Then, you can do something like this:

```
If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, Split(excludeSheets,","))) Then
    'code will manipulate the sheets which are not found in the array
    MsgBox sh.Name & " is not excluded!"
Else:
    Msgbox sh.Name & " is excluded!"
End If
```

**UPDATE**

Anticipating your new code, my guess is that you did not assign the `sh` variable.

You can do this in a loop strucutre:

```
Sub ShowMeTheSheets()

    Dim sh as Worksheet
    Const excludeSheets as String = "Apples,Oranges,Grapes,David,Hector,Sheet1"

    For each sh in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets  'Assigns a Worksheet Object to the sh Variable.
        If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, Split(excludeSheets,","))) Then
            'code will manipulate the sheets which are not found in the array
            MsgBox sh.Name & " is not excluded!"
        Else:
            Msgbox sh.Name & " is excluded!"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: David I get a Run-Time error

object variabe or With block variable not set

Comment: A runtime error can't happen in the code I've provided, unless the rest of your code is wrong.  Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't help you.  If the error is raising on the `If IsError` line, then I would guess you did not properly assign an object to the `sh` variable.  Please revise your original question to include the code you are currently trying to execute, and let me know which line raises the error.